# How to modify foundation datepicker year range?

Tags: datepicker, zurb-foundation

I have some code from foundation datepicker [[https://github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/foundation-datepicker]](https://github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/foundation-datepicker). My question, how to modify year range **-2;+2** only. And how to modify second field(#dpd2) become date+1 and hide date before?

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var checkin = $('#dpd1').fdatepicker({
                    onRender: function (date) {
                        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                    }
                }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
                        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
                        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
                        checkout.setValue(newDate);
                    }
                    checkin.hide();
                    $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
                }).data('datepicker');
                var checkout = $('#dpd2').fdatepicker({
                    onRender: function (date) {
                        return date.valueOf() < checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                    }
                }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                    checkout.hide();
                }).data('datepicker');
            });
```

Say thank you to helping me. :)